# css issue when display background image in a element

Tags: css, background, background-image

i got a issue, let say i want to display a background image for a  link

```
                  |   words   |
```

the bars mean the start/end of the link, it doesn`t actually exist

and i  want the background image display horizontally, but not start from the bar, and end at the bar,

i want it start 13px away from the left bar and 13px away from the right bar??

i know there is a background-position in css, but can i ask the background-position to specify the 13px for me???

Answer (score 1):

The following code does what you need:

```
<style>
    .biglink {
        margin: 0 13px 0 13px;
        background: url('background.png') no-repeat center center;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe background obeys the `padding` and `margin` css styles, so you could set `margin-left: 13px;` and `margin-right: 13px;`.